# Filter IEnumerable<T> in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my `workorder` table I have a foreign key to my `comments` table: (This works)

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; private set; }
```

A comment has a `CommentType` of `1` for a requestor or `2` for admin.  In my view, to display only the admin comments I do something like: (This also works)

```
@pir.Comments.Where(c => c.CommentTypeId == 2)
```

I don't want to have the `where` clause in my view, I would rather have it in the model.  I want to add a property in my model to automatically have filtered just the admin comments.  This is what I have tried:

Add a new property:

```
public IEnumerable<Comment> AdminComments { get; set; }
```

Create a constructor:

```
public WorkOrder()
{
    this.AdminComments = Comments. ????  There is no .where to do the filter
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `using System.Linq;` in order to use LINQ methods.

Comment: do you think it is bad to add `if (this.Comments.Count() > 0` in the constructor to prevent `Value cannot be null` error or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Do you know why comments would always be null in the model, but it works fine in the view?